Conditionally suppress header and footer using a formula
I’m working on a Crystal Report where I need to conditionally hide the page header and footer for specific sections of my report. My report layout includes a main report followed by several subreports. The challenge arises with the following layout:

Header

Main Report

Subreport 1

Subreport 2

Section where I set the formula to hide the header and footer (this section has no content)

Subreport 3 (has header but footer is successfully hidden)

Subreport 4 (successfully has no header/footer)

Subreport 5 (successfully has no header/footer)


I believe the issue is that the header is printed before the formula is executed, which is why the header still appears while the footer is hidden.
Here is what the header/footer suppress formula looks like:
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared booleanvar HideFooterAndHeader
If HideFooterAndHeader = true then true else false

Here is what the HidePageHeaderAndFooter formula looks like:
WhilePrintingRecordsShared booleanvar HideFooterAndHeader := true;

I tried placing the formula in different sections to hide the header and footer, and used the NewPage function, but it either caused unwanted page breaks or didn't fully solve the problem.

If you treat them as "different" reports, it makes the whole process simpler. You just concatenate them if you have to. "Multi-pass" reporting.
